# Javascript load a random image

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

I want to create a javascript function that will load a random image when the function da_image is called. I want the image to load onto a canvas I have set up. Is there a clear error in my code? Nothing is currently displaying.

```
var images = [
                    "http://circlesfordialogue.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/LAURA-LET%C2%B4S-CIRCLE-UP-2014-12-08.jpg",
                    "http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/ConcentricCircles_1000.gif", 
                    "http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/12/BezierCircleFigure3.png"

            ];
            function da_image(){
                var file = images[0]; 
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(){
                        var img = new Image();
                        img.src = reader.result;
                        img.onerror = function(){
                            reset_canvas();
                            o.font = '30px sans-serif'
                            o.fillText('Error: Invalid Image ' + file.name, 50, 100);
                        }
                        img.onload = function(){
                            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'Recognizing Text... This may take a while...'
                            reset_canvas();
                            var rat = Math.min(c.width / img.width, c.height / img.height);
                            o.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width * rat, img.height * rat)
                            var tmp = document.createElement('canvas')
                            tmp.width = img.width;
                            tmp.height = img.height;
                            var ctx = tmp.getContext('2d')
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
                            var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, tmp.width, tmp.height);
                            runOCR(image_data, true)
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: So what's the FileReader for, you never read a file, hence the `onload` callback never fires.

Comment: Oh wait, you're actually reading a cross domain url as a file inside the onload handler. That won't work, first of all there's the same origin policy, and secondly you don't need to read the image at all, and reading inside the onload handler won't work, just draw it in the canvas, but you won't be able to modify the image, due again to the same origin policy.

Comment: And then there's the undefined variable `c`, it this code just copy / pasted ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have put in this code from the beginning:                                    var c = document.getElementById('c'),
o = c.getContext('2d');

Answer (score 0):

The onload handler is triggered when the image is loaded. When the image is already loaded when you set an onload handler, it doesn't get triggered.

So always set the `.src` attribute after you set the `.onload` function.